# Where is the byte Array?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, winsock, gdi

I have C++ code that uses GDI to take a screenshot of the environment, and GDI+ to compress it into a JPG. I want to send the image over TCP, and for that I need to know where the byte array that contains the image is so I can put it into a char array.

This is my code:

```
void screenshot() {
    using namespace Gdiplus;
    IStream* istream;
    HRESULT res = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, true, &istream);
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    {
        HDC scrdc, memdc;
        HBITMAP membit;
        scrdc = ::GetDC(0);
        int Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
        int Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(scrdc);
        membit = CreateCompatibleBitmap(scrdc, Width, Height);
        HBITMAP hOldBitmap =(HBITMAP) SelectObject(memdc, membit);
        BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, Width, Height, scrdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(membit, NULL);
        CLSID clsid;
        GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid); //type of image to save
```

What I am looking for is the byte array that has been put inside my JPEG file to send it over TCP as a char array buffer.

```
        bitmap.Save(L"print.jpeg", &clsid, NULL); //name of the file
```

Right up here

```
        bitmap.Save(istream, &clsid, NULL);

        delete &clsid;
        DeleteObject(memdc);
        DeleteObject(membit);
        ::ReleaseDC(0,scrdc);
    }
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    istream->Release();
}
```

I have tried to receive information between the variables using `std::cout` but I couldn't get any useful information.

Comment: Tactical note: Usually too many sharp corners in a screen shot to make a good jpeg.

Comment: Did you copy this code? Or write it yourself? Have a look at [CBitmap::GetBitmapBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbitmap-class?view=msvc-170#getbitmapbits) there are more examples online of its usage. (You can get a CBitmap from the handle you have)

Comment: Are you intending to send the compressed .JPG data or the raw/uncompressed bitmap data that the .jpg data decompresses to?

Comment: screenshots are often much better stored in png because the size would be smaller and quality is better, unless you're capturing a screenshot showing a camera photo

Comment: When you have an IStream you can also use [IStream_Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-istream_read) function from winapi to get the data out. That will probably also get you the jpeg encoded data.

Comment: `CLSID clsid;` creates an object with automatic lifetime. `delete &clsid;` is meaningless, and the behavior is undefined.

Comment: *The [GetDIBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdibits) function retrieves the bits of the specified compatible bitmap and copies them into a buffer as a DIB using the specified format. For an example, see [Capturing an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/capturing-an-image)*.